# How does Twitter resolve tweeted images for twitpic, yfrog, instagram

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

When you select a tweet in twitter the right pane appears.  If the tweet has a twitpic, yfrog, or instagram path, it will display the image.  Twitter will do this for video and a few other networks as well.  Is there a library available that has this all this functionality or how is this accomplished?  I'm mostly interested in resolving images tweeted and am looking for a PHP or JS solution.

Answer (score 3):

Twitter uses those services' APIs:

http://twitpic.com/api.do

http://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/

http://instagram.com/developer/

etc.

Answer (score 3):

use jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contentbox").keyup(function() {
        var content = $(this).val();
        var urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
        // Filtering URL from the content using regular expressions
        var url = content.match(urlRegex);

        if (url.length > 0) {
            $("#linkbox").slideDown('show');
            $("#linkbox").html("<img src='link_loader.gif'>");
            // Getting cross domain data
            $.get("urlget.php?url=" + url, function(response) {
                // Loading <title></title>data
                var title = (/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/m).exec(response)[1];
                // Loading first .png image src='' data
                var logo = (/src='(.*?).png'/m).exec(response)[1];
                $("#linkbox").html("<img src='" + logo + ".png' class='img'/><div><b>" + title + "</b><br/>" + url)
            });

        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://www.9lessons.info/2010/06/facebook-like-extracting-url-data-with.html

Answer (score 0):

well u can do something like this without using these above libraries. When u get the page with your tweets parse the `urls` for any images("twitpic" or "yfrog") and then use ajax to silently download the images in the background and then when user selects the tweet u show the image. The hard part is parsing the url to figure out the images.
i havent tried this but this should work